# Dynamic Video Tag and Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, knockout.js, html5-video

I'm trying to dynamically change the video source of a `video` tag using Knockout.  This is the code:

```
<div data-bind="if: resource().encodingformats() != ''">
    <video style="max-width: 100%;" controls>
        <!-- ko with: resource() -->
        <source data-bind="attr:{ src: webmUrl }" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
        <source data-bind="attr:{ src: oggUrl }" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
        <source data-bind="attr:{ src: mp4Url }" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </video>
</div>
```

I'm using an `if` binding to make sure that a brand new video tag is rendered whenever the current resource is changed.

This works in all browsers except Firefox.  Firefox gives me an error (warning, actually) of

```
<source> element has no "src" attribute. Media resource load failed.
```

I'm guessing the `source` element is getting rendered for a split second without the `src` attribute set, which is causing it to bomb?

Is there an easy way to fix this?  I suppose I could just bind the entire video's html, but that seems overly sloppy.  Is there an easy way to get Firefox to work with the same code that otherwise works fine in IE9?

---

**EDIT**

I should also mention that after using Firebug to look at the html generated, I coped the entire `source` tags into my code, and that worked fine.  In other words, I ditched the knockout bindings for a minute, and copied in the html that knockout was generating, and everything worked.

The problem most certainly is that Firefox is extremely picky about how the source tags are generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the real problem above is that Firefox fires off the "error" event even when there's no error.

So, if you're subscribing to this event so that you can fall back to a flash player for IE8 users, be sure to check your "error" handler to make sure there's actually an error.

```
$(videoTag).one("error", function(){
    //sometimes Firefox fires this event even though there's no error :-/
    if (!this.error) return;
```

Once you do that, Firefox should happily let you bind the video tag's sources as I did above.

Comment: Glad that you identified the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it would be similar to this: [Controlling Flash Plugins with Knockout.js, Conflicting jQuery.tmpl and Knockout-Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051283/controlling-flash-plugins-with-knockout-js-conflicting-jquery-tmpl-and-knockout).

Not very elegant, but the easiest solution is to use the `html` binding with a string that includes your elements. This ensures that there will never be a `source` tag that does not include a `src` attribute.

A better choice might be to whip up a custom binding that takes in a `resource`, creates a string containing all of the "source" tags, and  then applies the `html` binding to the container element (or uses something like jQuery to append the elements).  That would be a more elegant solution. Might need to generate the entire `video` tag, not sure how picky FF is about it.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was expecting.  Thank you for the answer Ryan.  So is it wrong for me to expect FF to at least be as good as IE here?  :-/

Comment: Well at least a custom binding would make it look clean in the markup and save you from building HTML in your view model.

Comment: Thanks for your time Ryan, but check out my answer below for what the real problem was.  I would love to have been in *that* development meeting...