# html5 <video> with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, knockout.js

I am trying to use HTML5 `video` tag with knockout.js, here is my code sample:

```
function AppViewModel() {
     this.courseUrl= ("http//www.google.com");
     this.vidUrl= ("/video/myvid.mp4");
};
var vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here is my html code:

```html
<video id="my_video" width="1000" height="500" autoplay>
    <source data-bind="attr: { src : vidUrl }">
</video>
<a data-bind="attr: { href: courseUrl }">Visit google</a>
```

As you can see from my code I am using same kind of code for calling a `href` and `src` of video. My `href` line works fine whereas `src` doesn't load the specified video (or any video) and it doesn't give any error.

Please let me know if I am not doing anything correctly.

TEMP SOLUTION:

For now, I am using normal js code to load video, this code is inside knockout's viewmodel function. This way I will have access to data coming through knockout variables. I haven't tested this thoroughly, but its working for now. My code now changes as follow:

```
 function AppViewModel() {
     this.courseUrl= ("http//www.google.com");
     var video =document.getElementById('my_video');
     video.src = "/video/myvid.mp4";
};
```

and html code is as follow:

```
<video id="my_video" width="640" height="480"  autoplay>

</video>
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Any errors on console? 404 maybe for video.

Comment: nope, its doesn't give any error. That's why I am stuck, i have no clue what is not working. I have tested the video path by giving the path directly to src of video, it works fine. But when i try to pass it from kockoutjs it doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting. I can [repro the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/dqsjftst/), would've expected an error shown in the console because the mp4 cannot be loaded from the jsfiddle domain. Have you tried if you're experiencing [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14404367/419956)?

Comment: no I am not facing that issue, i am working on chrome and i am not getting the error the user was getting in that issue. I was going through inspect page, it shows me this <source data-bind="attr : { src : vidUrl }" type="video/mp4" src="/video/myvid.mp4">, this means its binding properly, just not displaying. Or am i wrong ?