# Not able to bind src attribute in embed tag using attr binding

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

The `textbox` binds fine, but the `src` attribute in the `embed` tag doesn't bind at all. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/pscr43sc/1/

```html
<input type='text' data-bind='value: 123'/>
<embed data-bind="attr: {src: 'http://google.com'}" />
```

Comment: Does `<embed src="http://google.com"/>` work without knockout ?

Comment: Try changing the embed tag to be `<embed ...></embed>`.  I have a feeling the tag is being broken up so the bindings are weird.

Comment: OP, I've removed all my previous comments to clean up the post a bit (I suggest you do the same), and remixed all of the info in it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *not* that the `src` attribute is not being bound by Knockout: that bit is working perfectly, as you can tell from this screenshot of your fiddle with the dev tools open:

[image: dev tools]

The `src` attribute gets set correctly by KnockoutJS.

You are experiencing (a variant of) [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2493706/419956) where the browser doesn't like the fact that `src` is dynamically changed on such elements. Mentioned workarounds mostly come down to re-creating the entire element, which is pretty easy to do with KnockoutJS.

Here's a "naive" example that allows for some "dirty" KnockoutJS code, as in that it contains some DOM manipulation inside the view:

```js
function RootViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.link = ko.observable("//placehold.it/50");
  self.embedHtml = ko.computed(function() {
    return "<embed src='" + self.link() + "' />"; // Might need some sanitation on "link()"
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```css
pre { background: white; padding: 10px; color: #333; font: 11px consolas; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="html: embedHtml"></div>
<hr>Change link: <input data-bind="value: link">
<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

If you change the link (e.g. change "50" to "200") and blur the input field, you'll see the change on the `embed` tag.

Note that the above is actually remixed from (and the solution should be attributed to @RPNiemeyer) [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057222/419956), which also goes on to suggest an alternative. With that alternative you'd create a custom binding handler that clones the `embed` node on view model updates, changes the `src` attribute, and then replaces the original node with the clone in the DOM. The upside there is that you have no DOM code inside your view model. The answer links to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rGP7z/) for an example.